# Keras: Binary_crossentropy has negative values

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm following [this tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) (section 6: Tying it All Together), with my own dataset. I can get the example in the tutorial working, no problem, with the sample dataset provided.

I'm getting a binary cross-entropy error that is negative, and no improvements as epochs progress. I'm pretty sure binary cross-entropy should always be positive, and I should see some improvement in the loss. I've truncated the sample output (and code call) below to 5 epochs. Others seem to run into similar problems sometimes when training CNNs, but I didn't see a clear solution in my case. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Sample output:

```
Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:2) -> (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX TITAN Black, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0)
10240/10240 [==============================] - 2s - loss: -5.5378 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: -7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/5
10240/10240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: -7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/5
10240/10240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: -7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/5
10240/10240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: -7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/5
10240/10240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: -7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

My code:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

dataset = np.loadtxt('train_rows.csv', delimiter=",")
testset = np.loadtxt('test_rows.csv', delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:, :62]
Y = dataset[:, 62]

X_test = testset[:, :62]
Y_test = testset[:, 62]

### create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=(62,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
## Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=5, batch_size=128)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I should have printed out my response variable. The categories were labelled as 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1, which confused the classifier.

Comment: In my case, I had an autoencoder with this problem. It turned out that 4 of my columns in my matrix had values larger than 1, whereas the remaining 284 columns were in the range [0,1]. Rebasing the columns with values larger than 1 (using their max values), fixed my issue.

Comment: I want to share my case too. I use a CNN U-Net for training image segmentation w/ cross binary-entropy. I happened to convert my masks from True/False to 255/0 and that confused the classifier and caused negative losses.

Comment: @PreetomSahaArko I normalized the values between 0 and 1
https://github.com/nicolefinnie/kaggle-dsb2018/blob/master/src/modules/unet.py#L61

Comment: thanks for sharing. Indeed, I've had the same target classes: [2, 1], that were remapped from the source values: [-1, 1]. With source values, loss is still sometimes negative. Log loss: `mean(y_true*log(y_pred) + (1-y_true)log(1-y_pred))`. Where you get log of a negative (which is undefined), the system ends up optimizing for only half of samples. Would be cool, if somebody could validate my thinking here.

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, incorrect labels is one of the primary culprits I've seen across several examples.

Comment: In my example, I had an autoencoder, and one side was normalized by 255, and the other side wasn't. The loss I was using in the model was a regular BCE Loss.

Comment: @ Nicole Finnie Hi, I face with the same issue. Can you tell me exactly how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting negative losses, then the solution is to coerce the target to be 0 or 1. In the OP's case, it was subtracting 1 from the target/label.

```py
Y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2])
Y -= 1                       # array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Depending on the use case, there are other ways to "coerce" the target to be either 1 or 0. One way is a boolean conditional check. For example, the following converts every value greater than 0 to 1 and all others to 0.

```py
Y = np.array([-1, 1, -1, 1])
Y = (Y > 0).astype(int)      # array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Another is `clip()`, which limits every value to be between 0 and 1. If the labels were 0/255, then it would do the job.

```py
Y = [0, 255, 0, 1]
Y = np.clip(Y, 0, 1)         # array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

---

###### How can the loss be negative?

The way `binary_crossentropy` is implemented in Keras ([1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b3ffea6602dbbb481e82312baa24fe657de83e11/keras/losses.py#L2431-L2434), [2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b3ffea6602dbbb481e82312baa24fe657de83e11/keras/backend.py#L5813-L5819)) is to coerce the predicted probabilities (`output` below) to be in the (0, 1) interval and return the result of the following computation.

```
bce = target * log(output) + (1 - target) * log(1 - output)
return mean(-bce)
```

Now, since `output` is between 0 and 1, `log(output)` and `log(1-output)` are both negative. If `target` is either 0 or 1, `bce` is negative, so `mean(-bce)` is a positive number which is the binary cross entropy loss. However, if target is not 0 or 1, this logic breaks down. In particular, if `target` is greater than 1 and `output` is sufficiently large, then `bce` would be positive and `mean(-bce)` would be negative.

---

A summarized implementation of `binary_crossentropy()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
epsilon_ = tf.keras.backend.epsilon()
target = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
output = tf.clip_by_value(output, epsilon_, 1 - epsilon_)

bce = target * tf.math.log(output + epsilon_)
bce += (1 - target) * tf.math.log(1 - output + epsilon_)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(-bce)
```